# Pandas dataframe self-dependency in data to fill a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with data as:

[image]

The value of "relation" is determined from the codeid. Leather has "codeid"=11 which is already appeared against bag, so in relation we put the value bag.
Same happens for shoes.

ToDo: Fill the value of "relation", by putting check on codeid in terms of dataframes. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Same codeid e.g. 11 can appear > twice. But the "relation" can have only value as bag because bag is the first one to have codeid=11. i have updated the picture as well.

Comment: Will the codes appear only twice? And should one take the name of the first appearance of the code only?

Answer (score 1):

If want only first dupe value to last duplicated use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `first` and then set `NaN` values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'name':list('brslp'),
                   'codeid':[11,12,13,11,13]})

df['relation'] = df.groupby('codeid')['name'].transform('first')
print (df)
   id name  codeid relation
0   1    b      11        b
1   2    r      12        r
2   3    s      13        s
3   4    l      11        b
4   5    p      13        s
```

---

```
#get first duplicated values of codeid
print (df['codeid'].duplicated(keep='last'))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: codeid, dtype: bool

#get all duplicated values of codeid with inverting boolenam mask by ~ for unique rows   
print (~df['codeid'].duplicated(keep=False))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: codeid, dtype: bool

#chain boolen mask together 
print (df['codeid'].duplicated(keep='last') | ~df['codeid'].duplicated(keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: codeid, dtype: bool
```

---

```
#replace True values by mask by NaN 
df.loc[df['codeid'].duplicated(keep='last') | 
       ~df['codeid'].duplicated(keep=False), 'relation'] = np.nan
print (df)
   id name  codeid relation
0   1    b      11      NaN
1   2    r      12      NaN
2   3    s      13      NaN
3   4    l      11        b
4   5    p      13        s
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain the code, as it seems to be working but it's not working at my end

Comment: @frozenshine - Can you explain more why not working? Problem in sample data or in real?

Comment: testing your logic on real data. the last statement is making all values NaN not just the first ones.

Comment: @frozenshine - hmmm, so real data are different like sample data, is possible add more rows, create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: No the data is exactly following same pattern that I showed. I only need to figure out why only np.nan line is making all rows as "nan".

Comment: @frozenshine - added more infromation/explanation to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to check it again. Could you tell why you used "first" in transform ? and what does it do?.  PLease also note that the value can appear more than twice and only the first occurence has null in relation.

Comment: @frozenshine - Can you change data for `PLease also note that the value can appear more than twice and only the first occurence has null in relation` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['bag', 11, 'null'], 
                  ['shoes', 12, 'null'], 
                  ['shopper', 13, 'null'], 
                  ['leather', 11, 'bag'], 
                  ['plastic', 13, 'shoes']], columns = ['name', 'codeid', 'relation'])

def codeid_analysis(rows):
    if rows['codeid'] == 11:
        rows['relation'] = 'bag'
    elif rows['codeid'] == 12:
        rows['relation'] = 'shirt' #for example. You should put what you want here
    elif rows['codeid'] == 13:
        rows['relation'] = 'pants' #for example. You should put what you want here
    return rows

result = df.apply(codeid_analysis, axis = 1)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, the question showed only sample data, and real data is quiet big. Cant use manual if and else. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not the optimal solution since it is costly to your memory, but here is my try. `df1` is created in order to hold the `null` values of the `relation` column, since it seems that nulls are the first occurrence. After some cleaning, the two dataframes are merged to provide into one.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['bag', 11, 'null'], 
                  ['shoes', 12, 'null'], 
                  ['shopper', 13, 'null'], 
                  ['leather', 11, 'bag'], 
                  ['plastic', 13, 'shopper'],
                  ['something',13,""]], columns = ['name', 'codeid', 'relation'])

df1=df.loc[df['relation'] == 'null'].copy()#create a df with only null values in relation
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], inplace=True)#drops the duplicates and retains the first entry
df1=df1.drop("relation",axis=1)#drop the unneeded column

final_df=pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='codeid', right_on='codeid')#merge the two dfs on the columns names
```